# Is where I live going to have a positive/negative effect on getting a novel published?

Tags: publishing

I live in Australia (or some place that is not the UK or the USA).

I wonder if the same percentage of QUALITY scripts get published in any place, but that in the big places, like the UK and the USA, there are many more scripts published that are of dubious quality, *making it seem as though it's "easier" to get published if you live in the States*.

**Is where I live going to have a positive/negative effect on getting a novel published?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your location will not have an effect on getting published. Publishers are in this business to make money and as much of it as possible. If you have a good manuscript they'll buy it whether you live in New York City, the middle of Australia or in an underground tunnel with dwarves.

In the old times, location was key because you needed to be near the publishing houses or wait forever for mail. But with the internet, you can submit manuscripts instantly and have a response in a reasonable amount of time. Contracts can be emailed and either scanner or faxed back, further cutting down on the time

Answer (score 2):

You live where you live. Generally, that isn't that huge a disadvantage.

The question you should be asking yourself: "is *my* writing of dubious quality?" If it isn't, you need not worry that publishers in your country don't publish such manuscripts. Maybe it just shows that they have taste.

Focus on making your writing better and worry about the rest later on.

Comment: It's a question that I've been wanting to ask people in the know about for some time. This seems like the perfect place to ask. Am on board with "make your writing better".

Comment: Improving your writing only increases your chances for getting published, of course, it's not a guarantee.